# Ruby/Chef: Temporary files are removed earlier than I need them to be

Tags: ruby, oracle11g, chef-infra

I have the following recipe:

```
require 'fileutils'
require 'zip'
#require 'rubygems'
#require 'progressbar'

oraclePath = "\\\\MyServ\\Oracle Client\\Oracle_11gR2\\win64_11gR2_client.zip"

begin
tmpDir = Dir.mktmpdir("ora-")

puts "#{tmpDir}"
FileUtils.cp_r("#{oraclePath}","#{tmpDir}")
Zip::File.open("#{tmpDir}/win64_11gR2_client.zip") do |zipfile|
  zipfile.each do |file|
    f_path = File.join("#{tmpDir}", file.name)
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(f_path))
    zipfile.extract(file, f_path)
  end
end

#temporary for testing
FileUtils.cp("c:/myresp.rsp", "#{tmpDir}/client")

system("#{tmpDir}/client/setup.exe -silent -responseFile \"#{tmpDir}/client/myresp.rsp\" -logLevel finest")

ensure
  # remove the temp directories
  FileUtils.remove_entry_secure tmpDir
end
```

My issue seems to be that the call to `setup.exe` in turn calls another cmd process... so I *think* I'm returning from the original `setup.exe` call before the installation is actually complete. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: `oraclePath` should be `ORACLE_PATH` because it should be a constant, and we use upper-case in snake_case for constants. Also, use single quotes instead of double-quotes, to get rid of the need to escape your backslashes and use forward-slashes because Ruby lets you use them in filenames: `'//MyServ/Oracle Client/Oracle_11gR2/win64_11gR2_client.zip'`. Also, `tmpDir` should be `tmp_dir` because local variables are snake_case in Ruby. And take advantage of `File.join` to build paths dynamically regardless of the OS.

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand what you mean by using File.join

Comment: Look it up. Look at your use of `File.open`, `FileUtils.cp`, and `system`. [File.join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-join) is the right way to build paths. Don't do it by concatenation or string interpolation..

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use Chef's execute resource, not Ruby's `system` command:

http://docs.opscode.com/chef/resources.html#execute

Comment: (but I'm not sure that helps with the sub process issue)